# Can I use MX records to deliver some addresses to Google Apps and some to my server?

Tags: email, mx-record, pipe, email-server

I have whm installed on my VPS, which my domain MX records are pointing to:

```
 0:mail.mydomain.com
```

and whm/cpanel has mail forwarding rules which pipes certain @mydomain email addresses into my CRM software.

But for certain email addresses I want to forward into Google Apps. For example, `sales@mydomain.com`, `support@mydomain.com` pipes into cPanel --> CRM (mail.mydomain.com) but `josh@mydomain.com` should be going to Google MX records.  Is that possible?

The reason why is I want to register for Google Apps such as analytics and other Google services under josh@mydomain.com.

My initial thoughts were to add a subdomain such as `josh@admin.mydomain.com` and point that subdomain's MX records to Google.. but I want to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

MX records work for the entire domain and there is no way to have one email address at a domain point to different MX records than another email address at the same domain.

It might be better to go the other way.  Set your `MX` records to point to Google and have them forward certain email addresses to your mail server.  You will get better reliability that way too.

It certainly *is* possible to have Postfix forward emails.  In `main.cf`:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

And in `/etc/postfix/generic`:

```
josh@example.com josh@gmail.com
```

Run `postmap generic` after editing the file and `postfix reload` to tell Postfix to reload its config.

If you're using something other than Postfix, add it to your question.